# My HP PageWide Pro Printer's ethernet port is constantly flashing

Tags: printer, ethernet, led, flashing

The ethernet port LED (green) of my HP PageWide Pro Printer is constantly flashing in a very high frequency. Permanent, it seems to be 24 hours x 365 days even though the printer is not in use most of the time. This extreme flash is visible on the back wall and very annoying. I can't move the printer. I could cover the LED somehow but I really would like to know what the h*** this printer is communicating all day all year so that the ethernet port shows traffic with constantly flickering LED. No other web based device I own or ever owned did this. Can I stop it? Could it even be that something strange is going on (spyware)?

Comment: Check for unwanted broadcast traffic on the printer’s network segment.

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty [serious potential security exploit (CVE-2017-2741)](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-2741/) for this (and other similar HP models) that could allow remote code execution.

If this device has been internet accessible and seems to be communicating with something, I would suggest investigating the following [HP Security Bulletin](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05462914), and taking steps to ensure that it is no longer vulnerable to this attack.